# How to optimize a gantt chart made with pgfgantt in spite of long task names?

Tags: pgfgantt

I am working on a draft proposal proposal for a European H2020 innovation call, using the EU RIA H2020 LaTeX template. It makes sense to supply several Gantt charts.  I am facing the situation where the tasks listed in the call have very long names, and it is impossible to fit the mandatory vertical A4 format (see MWE). I have tried different tricks, but nothing worked well, while writing the tasks on two lines would seem the obvious path. Changing the task names to shorter ones is not advisable, since evaluators check how well the proposal fits the call requirements. Any suggestion ?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid] {1}{12}
\gantttitle{2018}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{State of the art \& prior art analysis}{1}{3} \\ 
\ganttbar{Define development orientations}{4}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Specify device utility management System physical interface}{6}{07} \\
\ganttbar{Develop/adapt/produce required sets of physical interface elements}{8}{12} 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either break the lines or you can introduce labels together with a legend.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid,bar label node/.append style={align=right}] {1}{12}
\gantttitle{2018}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{State of the art \& prior art analysis}{1}{3} \\ 
\ganttbar{Define development orientations}{4}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Specify device utility management\\ System physical interface}{6}{07} \\
\ganttbar{Develop/adapt/produce required\\ sets of physical interface elements}{8}{12} 
\end{ganttchart}
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid] {1}{12}
\gantttitle{2018}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{Task A}{1}{3} \\ 
\ganttbar{Task B}{4}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Task C}{6}{07} \\
\ganttbar{Task D}{8}{12} 
\end{ganttchart}
\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}\linewidth{@{}lX@{}}
  Task A & State of the art \& prior art analysis\\
  Task B & Define development orientations\\
  Task C & Specify device utility management System physical interface\\
  Task D & Develop/adapt/produce required sets of physical interface elements
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The "bar label node/.append style={align=right}" was the solution I was dreaming of... The second option as well as David's Carlisle's proposal are less appealing, because in the call, the items are not abbreviated, and I prefer not to introduce another level. There may be several Gantt charts on the same page and footnotes would be confusing also.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[vgrid] {1}{12}
\gantttitle{2018}{12} \\
\gantttitlelist{1,...,12}{1} \\
\ganttbar{State\footnotemark}{1}{3} \\ 
\ganttbar{Define\footnotemark}{4}{5} \\
\ganttbar{Specify\footnotemark}{6}{07} \\
\ganttbar{Develop\footnotemark}{8}{12} 
\end{ganttchart}

\footnotetext[1]{State of the art \& prior art analysis}

\footnotetext[2]{Define development orientations}

\footnotetext[3]{Specify device utility management System physical interface}

\footnotetext[4]{Develop/adapt/produce required sets of physical interface elements}

\end{document}
```